# separate internet connection for Guest OS

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have 2 internet connections `Wifi` and `Usb Threaded Mobile Internet Connetion` host is connected with wifi and GuestOS on VMWare also uses `WiFi` through `NAT`.  I want to use `Mobile internet` connection on VMWare and `WiFi` on Host Machine.
Please guide me.

Comment: Just set that USB device as the primary network interface card for the guest os.

Comment: @steve no option here to set the Interface card